# Bayesian search theory - How to prove Blackwell result on optimal strategy

Tags: probability, optimization, bayesian

I am currently working on the best strategies to find objects in the sea.

My situation is as follows: a sunken submarine is in the sea modeled by a square matrix whose size is arbitrary, assume it is *n*. So the submarine has to be found within one of the *n²* boxes of the grid.

We have no exact idea at the beginning of the search about the submarine's position.

Let *p(i,j)* the probability of finding the wreck at *(i,j)*.
Let *c(i,j)* the cost of searching at the position *(i,j)*. (We can assume for example that this cost only depends on the Euclidian distance between our boat's position and the submarine's location).

The submarine is not moving, however at each step the boat travels. So we have to reconsider the costs at each search.

Finally let *q* the probability of successfully finding the wreck when searching in the right box.

At each step of the search we look into one of the boxes, we repeat this operation until we find the submarine.

And if one search is unsuccessful we update the probabilities using Bayes Theorem as explained in this article :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_search_theory

My point is **to prove**, if it is possible, the result described in *Searching in boxes* of the previous article, that states that the optimal policy in order to find the submarine is to look at each step in the box which maximizes:

## $\dfrac{p_{i,j}q}{c_{i,j}} $

Can anyone help me prove this result please?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: a) Where you write "this cost only depends on the Euclidian distance between our boat's position and the submarine's position" – by "the submarine's position", I think you mean the position being searched? (Both because that would make more sense and because otherwise the cost would be unknown.) b) Is the boat stationary, or does it travel to the search positions? If it travels, the costs will change over time, and I can't imagine that in this case a simple expression like the one you quote at the end would be optimal.

Comment: a) Yes, the submarine is at a fixed location. I will correct it for more clarity, thank you. b) No, the boat moves until the submarine is found. Yes, me neither, and therefore I can't see how to prove it, or at least find an optimal strategy. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I interpret the Wikipedia article to be about a problem with fixed costs. I think your problem with position-dependent costs that change at every step is much more difficult and will require more of a combinatorial optimization approach.

Comment: If the costs are fixed, then I guess that the given result is useless in this concrete example. Do you have any resources I could check for making my ideas clearer  please? I could not find Blackwell's proof, that would maybe have helped me for understanding better the problem, so at least I would know the hypothesis under which the result is true. I only found this paper that dealt with the problem of searching n objects in m boxes : https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176349665 but my lack of expertise is making me unable of fully understanding the proofs.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the solution in the Wikipedia article assumes fixed costs, and thus doesn’t apply to your case of position-dependent costs.

Note also that $q$ depends on the box in that article. If it doesn’t, as in your case, there’s no need to include it in the ratio.

I'll combine the indices $i,j$ into a single index $k$ for conciseness. I'll denote the “attractiveness” $\frac{p_k}{c_k}$ by $a_k$.

If a strategy doesn’t always search the most attractive box that maximizes the current value of $a_k$, then it must include two consecutive searches which search the less attractive box of the two first.

To see this, note that the strategy eventually returns to every box. Assume box $b$ is the most attractive at time $t_1$ but box $c$ is picked instead. Until $b$ eventually gets picked at time $t_2$, it receives the same Bayesian update factors as other boxes that aren’t picked receive, while boxes that are picked and searched in vain receive lower update factors. Thus, when $b$ gets picked at $t_2$, it has the attractiveness it had at $t_1$ multiplied by the maximal Bayesian update factors, and thus a higher attractiveness than that of $c$ at $t_1$ multiplied by these same factors. Thus, there must be a first time after $t_1$ at which a box is picked that has higher attractiveness than $c$ would have had with maximal update factors, and this box must have had higher attractiveness than the one searched immediately before it.

If neither of these two consecutive searches succeeds, it doesn’t matter in which order they were performed. So assume that one of them succeeds. This is the search in box $1$ with probability $p_1'=\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}$ and the search in box $2$ with probability $p_2'=\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2}$ (where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the values before the first search). If we search box $1$ first and then box $2$, the expected cost is $p_1'c_1+p_2'(c_1+c_2)$, whereas if we search box $2$ first and then box $1$, the expected cost is $p_2'c_2+p_1'(c_1+c_2)$. The difference is $p_2'c_1-p_1'c_2=\frac{c_1c_2}{p_1+p_2}(a_2-a_1)$. Thus, in two consecutive searches, the more attractive box must be searched first to minimize the expected cost. Since the strategy doesn’t do this, it cannot be optimal. Thus the optimal strategy always searches the currently most attractive box.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. I need clarification on the following points please : 1) why do we have "and this box must have had higher attractiveness than the one searched immediately before it."? 2) how do you determine the probability p1' and p2'? 3) How do you calculate the expected cost? There is something I am missing to understand this proof.

Comment: @Axel: 1) This is the first time after $t_1$ at which a box (say, $d$) is picked that has higher attractiveness than $c$ would have had with maximal update factors. Thus, at $t_1-1$, while $d$ at that point also had higher attractiveness than $c$ would have had with maximal update factors (otherwise it couldn't have had them at $t_1$), another box was picked that didn't, and thus had lower attractiveness than $d$.

Comment: In symbols: If $f(t)$ denotes the attractiveness $c$ would have had with maximal update factors, $w(t)$ denotes the box picked at time $t$ and $a(x,t)$ denotes the attractiveness of box $x$ at time $t$, then $t_1$ is the first time such that $a(w(t_1),t_1)\gt f(t_1)$; this implies also $a(w(t_1),t_1-1)\gt f(t_1-1)$, whereas $a(w(t_1-1),t_1-1)\le f(t_1-1)$, and thus $a(w(t_1-1),t_1-1)\lt a(w(t_1),t_1-1)$.

Comment: @Axel: $p_1'$ and $p_2'$ are just the conditional probabilities that the search in box $1$ and $2$, respectively, succeeds, given that exactly one ot them succeeds and the one in box $i$ succeeds with probability $p_i$.

Comment: @Axel: The expected cost is calculated according to the definition of the expected value: The sum of the products of the probabilities with the corresponding costs. Under the condition that the search in box $1$ or $2$ succeeds, if we search box $1$ first, then with probability $p_1'$ the first search in box $1$ succeeds, leading to a cost $c_1$, and with probability $p_2'$ the second search in box $2$ succeeds, leading to a cost $c_1+c_2$, so the expected cost in this case is $p_1'c_1+p_2'(c_1+c_2)$; and analogously for the other case.